# Multi Language website in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

**I have built a complete website in mvc4. Now I have to make it localize to two langauages English and Norwegian language. Please  Guide me how can I achieve it with minimum effort.**

Comment: You can easily do what you want using the ResourceFiles + LocalizationRoute + LocalizationAttribute GlobalFilter approach [described in this guide][1].

  [1]: http://www.ryadel.com/en/setup-a-multi-language-website-using-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the asp.net site there is a complete chapter on internationalization, read it.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/internationalization

Comment: The page is not jet available.

Comment: Have a look here then ... http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/advanced